# How can I create a group from a DOM object with Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to create a group to an object that I have put in the DOM but I don't know how since it doesn't have a key to set it in the `preload()` function I have preloaded a span element, and in the `create()` I have created an element in the DOM.

```
preload(){
    this.span = document.createElement('span')
}

create(){
  this.img = '/assets/sprites/shouko.png'

    this.span.style = `background: url("${this.img}"); background-size: cover; width: 60px; height: 60px; font-weight: bold`;

    this.element = this.add.dom(400, 300, this.span)

    this.physics.add.existing(this.element, false);// add sptite

    this.element.body.setOffset(-(this.element.displayWidth / 2), -(this.element.displayHeight / 2));
    this.element.body.setVelocity(100, 200);
    this.element.body.setBounce(1, 1);
    this.element.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}
```

Comment: Please break that long string of words into sentences so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I assume you want a *phaser* - group, with ***dom elements***.

So in this special case, I would create the ***dom element*** with the phaser method `this.add.dom().createElement(...)` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement.html#createElement__anchor)), and add them to a phaser group.

**Here a working Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    parent: 'phaser-parent',
    dom: {
        createContainer: true
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    
    let imgUrl = 'http://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/copy-that-floppy.png';
    let style = `background: url("${imgUrl}"); background-size: cover; width: 60px; height: 60px`;
    var group = this.add.group();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      var element = this.add.dom().createElement('span', style);
      
      this.physics.add.existing(element, false);
      
      element.x = 50 * (i+1);
      element.y = 50 * (i+1);
      element.body.setOffset(-(element.displayWidth / 2), -(element.displayHeight / 2));
      element.body.setVelocity(100, 200);
      element.body.setBounce(1, 1);
      element.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
      
      group.add(element);
    }

}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<div id="phaser-parent"></div>
```